# OPENJSON SQL call to API with record pagination - result count varies and is less than total records

Tags: json, sql-server, api

Using an API call get all of the emails in a given list or segment. The endpoint uses batching to return the records, so for a large list or segment multiple calls will need to be made to get all of the records.

Successful requests will include a JSON object containing a list of records containing profile IDs and emails and **potentially a marker*** if there are more records available.

Looping through each URL and assigning the marker to a variable. On the next call the URL is updated to get that page. 
No errors. Looping is successful. In the end the results count is ~89 less than what the web application displays. Run it again, this time its ~91 less.

```
    DECLARE GetProfiles CURSOR FOR
        SELECT BRAND, VARURL FROM #URLS
    OPEN GetProfiles
    FETCH NEXT FROM GetProfiles INTO @varBrand, @varURL
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        WHILE (@varMarker IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#IDS') IS NOT NULL BEGIN TRUNCATE TABLE #IDS END --CLEAR THE TABLE
            INSERT INTO #IDS
            SELECT ID, 
                  EMAIL,
                  MARKER 
            FROM OPENJSON(CURL.XGET('',@VarURL))
            WITH 
                (
                  RecordsJSON nvarchar(max) '$.records' as JSON,
                  Marker NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.marker'
                ) Records           
                OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Records.RecordsJSON)
                WITH
                    (
                        ID NVARCHAR(8) '$.id',  
                        Email NVARCHAR(120) '$.email'
                    ) Profiles

                SELECT TOP 1 @varMarker = Marker FROM #IDs
                INSERT INTO k.MARKERSTRACKING VALUES (@varMarker+'--------------')

                WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01' 
                INSERT INTO k.Profiles2  
                SELECT  @varBrand,
                        I.PROFILEID, 
                        I.EMAIL,
                        I.MARKER
                FROM #IDS I 
                LEFT JOIN k.Profiles2 A 
                ON I.ProfileID = A.PROFILEID 
                WHERE (A.PROFILEID IS NULL AND I.PROFILEID IS NOT NULL)
                IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#IDS') IS NOT NULL BEGIN TRUNCATE TABLE #IDS END

        END
        WHILE (@varMarker IS NOT NULL)  --> chain the lists via 'marker' values
        BEGIN --> PROCESS

            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#IDS') IS NOT NULL BEGIN TRUNCATE TABLE #IDS END
            SET @varURLMarker = @varURL + '&marker='+@varMarker
```

--(similar looping segment)

Expect a finite number and each run produces less that that number.

Is there some behavior challenges with calling out to an api over openjson?

This is my first time calling api in code.  I already added a 1 second wait inside the loops.